# Why am I not able to use the logging module with SMTPHandler to send emails?

Tags: python, email, logging

I am trying very hard to get the logging module to be able to send emails, but I keep getting errors and nothing is working.  My code and the error is below.  How do I fix this to send emails?

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger("name")
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> import logging.handlers
>>> mail_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler("smtp.gmail.com", "lenox.ben@gmail.com", "lenox.ben@gmail.com", "Testing", credentials=("lenox.ben@gmail.com", "Bl12224381"))
>>> mail_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> mail_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(message)s"))
>>> logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
>>> logger.info("Test email")

--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 1007, in emit
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.mailhost, port, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out
Call stack:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 144, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 474, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
Message: 'Test email'
Arguments: ()
```

Comment: Have you adapted your Gmail settings to accept 'unsafe applications'? Don't pin me on the exact name, but you need to alter those settings in Gmail for it to accept automated systems like these to access your account.

Comment: I just tried to change the "Allow less secure apps" setting but that didn't allow it to work.

Comment: That's the one. Shame it didn't work. Time-out suggests a connection issue? Those are the only bits of knowledge I could provide for this issue. Good luck!